# Will I get American AAdvantage miles when flying a Qantas flight operated by Emirates?

Tags: loyalty-programs, american-airlines, emirates, qantas

I normally collect AAdvantage points with American Airlines. I'm considering booking a Qantas flight (LHR->DXB), but some of the flights, whilst having a Qantas flight number, are operated by Emirates. Will these still enable me to earn AAdvantage points (since Qantas is a Oneworld airline). Are there any non-obvious downsides to taking the Emirates flight?

*Related*: [Can I use the Emirates lounge at LHR with a flight booked on a Qantas codeshare? (AAdvantage Exec Plat)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/can-i-use-the-emirates-lounge-at-lhr-with-a-flight-booked-on-a-qantas-codeshare)

Comment: If you were crediting to the BA Executive Club, and booked on the Qantas flight number, then [you would get Avios and Tier points](http://www.headforpoints.com/2015/11/05/earning-avios-and-ba-tier-points-when-flying-emirates-proof-it-works/). I'd suggest you check for similar wording in the AAdvantage program T&Cs, and see if they have a similar special exemption for QF-numbered non-OneWorld metal or not

Comment: It is worth noting that Qantas operated by non-oneworld appears to be an exception to the usual oneworld policy—"when flying on a oneworld-marketed flight, you only get miles if the flight is operated by oneworld". It may be that this was arranged with Emirates and oneworld when they signed their joint venture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. At this writing, nothing in the [AAdvantage Terms and Conditions](https://www.aa.com/i18n/AAdvantage/termsConditions.jsp) specifically excludes earnings on Emirates-operated flights. The [Qantas partner page](https://www.aa.com/i18n/AAdvantage/earnMiles/airlines/qantas.jsp) indicates

> Earn elite-qualifying AAdvantage miles when you fly on Qantas marketed and operated flights **as well as Qantas Airways codeshare flights**. Simply:
>
> - Buy an eligible published fare ticket booked in an eligible code
> - Fly an eligible route

The accrual table is also provided on the partner page. At this writing, only Qantas codeshares operated by Jetstar are specifically excluded from earning AA miles. Other QF-coded flights should be fine, provided it is not prohibited in the fare rules.

The FlyerTalk wikis on [Earning AA miles on Emirates and other airlines via Qantas codeshare](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/american-airlines-aadvantage/1580771-earning-aa-miles-emirates-other-airlines-via-qantas-codeshare.html) and [Miles on Qantas / QF codeshare operated by other airlines](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/american-airlines-aadvantage/1439865-miles-qantas-qf-codeshare-operated-other-airlines-ek-etc-consolidated-4.html) as of August 2015 also seem to confirm that it is possible, with  various anecdotal reports of success. FlyerTalk is generally up-to-date on such matters.

> N.B. Earning AAdvantage miles flying on EY and other non-oneworld operated flights as a QANTAS codeshare / marketed flight is an *exception* to oneworld rules that essentially state that to earn miles one must fly a oneworld marketed flight operated by a oneworld airline. See post #4 for more.

and

> To reiterate: one may earn AAdvantage miles flying an Emirates (or Air Fiji, Air Tahiti Nui, etc.) operated flight if it is marketed by QANTAS / a Qantas codeshare.

[Further discussion from 2013](http://www.travelingbetter.com/showthread.php?t=5453) at TravelingBetter.com.

Comment: I can confirm that having done this now, I did indeed get the miles. Note that Qantas flights when earnt on AAdvantage are rather stingy on the mileage amounts though - check the ticket type carefully on the American website to see how many miles you'll get.

Answer (score 4):

Can confirm that AA will honor the One World miles.  I flew on a Qantas booked ticket last week, used my AA FF# and the return flight was operated by Emirates and I got the same miles credit as I did on the inbound flight operated by Qantas.  Yeah!