# Can I use the Emirates lounge at LHR with a flight booked on a Qantas codeshare? (AAdvantage Exec Plat)

Tags: american-airlines, lounges, emirates, qantas

I am AAdvantage Exec Platinum with American Airlines. I've booked a Qantas codeshare flight, operated by Emirates. Which lounge(s) can I use at Heathrow (Terminal 3)? I assume I can use any Oneworld lounge, including the Qantas one. Can I also use the Emirates lounge? Which lounge can I use on a return journey from Dubai?

Comment: What class of ticket have you booked?

Comment: An economy ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although in the end I didn't actually try, it seems the answer is [**no**](https://www.oneworld.com/ffp/lounge-access):

> To be eligible, you must be departing on a flight that is both
>   marketed and operated by a oneworld member airline.

It also appears that my OneWorld status didn't allow First class check-in or early boarding either.

Comment: Don't believe what oneworld.com says, they might try to set the rules but the airlines don't always follow them. Qantas and Emirates is a special case. I suspect you'd have got access to the QF lounge (on the QF codeshare) but not the EK lounge. I agree, no priority boarding on the EK metal.

Comment: @Calchas there is no QF lounge at Heathrow :) Qantas use BA's.